# Stack Level Too Deep (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm getting a stack level too deep error on heroku but not on development. I've narrowed it down to a file but have no idea why this file is causing an error. Here's the file (_sidebar.html.haml):

```
.col-md-12
  .page-header
    %h3= link_to 'Texthub', root_path
  %h4{style: 'font-weight:normal;'}= "Your number: #{display_phone_number}"
  - if current_user.company.has_name?
    = link_to current_user.company.name, current_user.company
    (
    = link_to 'Invite', new_user_invitation_path
    )
  - else
    = link_to 'Set Company Name', edit_company_path(current_user.company)
  %br
  = link_to 'Add Customer', new_customer_path
  %br
  %br
  - @sidebar_customers.each do |customer|
    = link_to customer.full_name, customer
    .badge= customer.not_viewed_count if customer.not_viewed_count > 0
    .pull-right
      %div{:class => "label label-#{aasm_state_btn_class(customer)}"}
        = customer.aasm_state.capitalize
    %br
  %br
  %br
  = link_to 'Customers', customers_path
  %br
  = link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path
  %br
  = link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

and the file that calls this partial:

```
%body
  .container-fluid
    .row-fluid{style: 'height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;'}
      .col-md-3{style: 'height:100%;'}
        - if user_signed_in?
          = render 'shared/sidebar'
      .col-md-9
        = bootstrap_flash
        = yield
```

what is causing this error? Stack trace:

```
2014-03-18T21:23:47.908176+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-03-18T21:23:47.908176+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-03-18T21:23:47.908176+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 23.125.128.198 at 2014-03-18 21:23:47 +0000
2014-03-18T21:23:47.908176+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 23.125.128.198 at 2014-03-18 21:23:47 +0000
2014-03-18T21:23:48.032467+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-03-18T21:23:48.032467+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-03-18T21:23:48.274600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/_dashboard.html.haml (92.2ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.274600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/_dashboard.html.haml (92.2ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.274787+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (95.1ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.274787+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (95.1ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.298939+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.haml (17.9ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.299189+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.haml (17.9ms)
2014-03-18T21:23:48.299693+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 267ms
2014-03-18T21:23:48.301532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=texthub.herokuapp.com request_id=53a31f14-ec01-41e3-b479-cd25b72ad081 fwd="23.125.128.198" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=406ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-03-18T21:23:48.299755+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 267ms
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb:19
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb:19
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-18T21:23:48.300625+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU stack trace added

Comment: Where is StringInquirer being used?

Comment: no idea...i dont know what that is. I've fixed a stack level too deep error a bunch of times already but it keeps popping up in different places, this is the weirdest thing. it's like this error is the default error for every error I encounter